# Why doesn't Polygonizer copy line ids to polygonized shapefile?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, polygonize

I am trying to convert a line shapefile into a polygon shapefile using Polygonizer plugin, and when my new polygons are created all the cells in my id field are "Null", although I have clicked "copy table field from line layer". I have tried both Polygonizer 2 and Polygonizer 2.1.

Any idea why the ids from my line layer are not copied to my polygonized shapefile?

Comment: Is this the [**Polygonizer plugin**](https://github.com/p0cisk/Polygonizer/blob/master/PolygonizerDialog.py) you are using?

Comment: Yes! Polygonizer plugin. I 've tried it with both versions 2 and 2.1 and still didn't work.

Comment: If you need to convert your lines to polygons, you can try 'Lines to polygons' tool (QGIS standard geoalgorithms) as well. It preserves attributes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tools that can handle convert line to polygon and both preserve the information in attribute table:

1. Using Lines to Polygons from `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgrithms -> Vector geometry tools -> Lines to Polygons`
2. Using Convert lines to polygons from `Processing toolbox -> SAGA -> Vector polygon tools -> Convert lines to polygons`

Example:

This is a polyline that has a specific `id` and a `Name` fields as you can see below:

[image]

Using the first tool from `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgrithms -> Vector geometry tools -> Lines to Polygons`

[image]

Using the second tool from `Processing toolbox -> SAGA -> Vector polygon tools -> Convert lines to polygons`

[image]

You do not need to use the Polygonizer plugin as you can achieve what you want using the above two tools.